# Error Connecting to GitHub from SVN

Tags: github, svn, version-control

I have followed the tutorial that allows SVN users to checkout a repositary from GitHub [Support for SVN clients](https://help.github.com/articles/support-for-subversion-clients/) and I have had no success in connecting to GitHub. Is this method still supported? If so what am I doing wrong?

The command I run is:

```
C:\dev\git>svn co https://github.com/kenster10/hello-world.git
```

The error I get is:

```
svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://github.com/kenster10/hello-world.git'
svn: E730061: Error running context: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

Comment: Why do you use the svn client to access GitHub?

Comment: We use to it to download binaries into our org that we want to version. To streamline everything we just want to use one tool which is SVN. The erfect world for us would be just to be able to use SVN client as outlined in the link. Sadly it doenst work at the moment. Due to internal policies we cannot use GitHub as our version control system for everything and downloading the Git client will add another tool to our already extensive toolbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should double-check whether there is any proxy or firewall that prevents you from contacting GitHub.

The same command works for me without issues:

```
C:\Users\Pavel.Lyalyakin>svn co https://github.com/kenster10/hello-world.git
A    hello-world.git\branches
A    hello-world.git\branches\readme-edits
A    hello-world.git\branches\readme-edits\README.md
A    hello-world.git\trunk
A    hello-world.git\trunk\README.md
Checked out revision 4.
```